¿Como hacer un requests desde python a una página que tiene recaptcha?
Estoy tratando de obtener información del siguiente enlace mediante un requests desde python. Sin embargo, al hacer el requests este es bloqueado, asumo que es por el recaptcha que tiene la página, ¿cómo podría evitar esto y poder acceder a la información de la página?

Si lo podes evitar, te vas a hacer millonario, porque justamente la idea del recaptcha es que no lo hagas automaticamente....

@gbianchi, lo entiendo, pero es que también estoy teniendo un problema al tratar de acceder desde una máquina virtual, antes me dejaba acceder de manera manual y extraer la información que necesitaba, ya ni eso me deja realizar
